# How to call a JS function from rails form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-events

I want to call a JS function when a button in my Rails form is clicked. The function is defined in the `.js.erb` file found below.

When I click the button, Chrome's JS console throws the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: logTime is not defined

I know this means it can't find the function, but I don't see why. Especially since I added `<%= javascript_include_tag "track.js.erb" %>` to the file. Any ideas?

Apologies up-front,  but my Google-fu yielded no results.

**_track_time_form.html.erb**

```
<div id="countdown-timer"></div>
<div id="playback-button">&#9658;</div>
<div id="track-time-form">
    <%= form_for @project, :url => { :action => "log_time" }, remote: true do |p| %>
        <ul>
            <li><%= p.label :project, "Project:"%><br>
            <%= p.collection_select(:id, current_user.projects, :id, :name) %></li>

            <%= p.hidden_field :time_logged, :value => 0 %> <!-- value set by script in log_time.js.erb -->

            <li><%= p.submit "Log time", id: "log-time-button", :onclick => "logTime()" %></li>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The function the handler is calling can be found here:

**track.js.erb**

```
//initialise form 
timeTrackingForm = window.open("", "", "height=700,width=500");
$(timeTrackingForm.document.body).html("<%= j render( :partial => 'track_time_form' ) %>");

//assign variables 
var timer = $("#countdown-timer", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var playbackControls = $("#playback-button", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var form = $("#track-time-form", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var formUl = $("#track-time-form ul", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var formLi = $("#track-time-form li", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var logTimeButton = $("#log-time-button", $(timeTrackingForm.document));
var timerPaused;

//initialise timer 
$(timeTrackingForm.document).ready(function(){
    initialiseTimer();
    style();
    $(playbackControls).click(function() {
        playOrPause();
    });
});

function initialiseTimer() {
    $(timer).timer({
        format: '%H:%M:%S'
    });
    $(timer).timer('pause');
    timerPaused = true;
}

function style() {
    $(timer).css({'color':'black','font-size':'50px', 'margin':'auto', 'width':'180px'});
    $(playbackControls).css({'color':'#290052', 'font-size':'50px', 'margin':'auto', 'width':'55px'});
    $(form).css({'width':'300px','margin':'auto'});
    $(formUl).css({'list-style-type':'none'});
    $(formLi).css({'margin':'0 0 25px 0','font-sizeL':'18px','font-family':'Arial'});
    $(logTimeButton).css({'width':'180px','font-size':'18px','background-color':'green','color':'white','margin-top':'15px'});
}

function playOrPause() {
    if (timerPaused == true) {
        $(timer).timer('resume');
        timerPaused = false;
    }
    else {
        $(timer).timer('pause')
        timerPaused = true;
    }
}

function logTime() {
    $(timer).timer('pause');
    var secondsTracked = $(timer).data('seconds');
    $('input:hidden').val(secondsTracked);
    $('#countdown-timer').timer('reset');
}
```

Comment: Can you find this specific js function when you view the source for the rendered page in the Sources tab in Chrome debugger?  Either it's not loading or some syntax error is preventing it from being valid Javascript when read by the browser, thus making it unavailable.

Comment: There's certainly no asset named "track.js.erb"; The erb is the server-side file that's processed to create "track.js".

Comment: Why don't you just set up a proper event listener in your javascript instead? `$('#track-time-form>form').submit(function(){ });`

Comment: @JECarterII Weirdly enough I'm not getting anything from the sources tab. Only "about:blank". Could this be because it's a popup?

Comment: @max your suggestion worked to a certain extent, but for some reason the script seems to stop executing after `$('input:hidden').val(secondsTracked);`. Any ideas why that may be?

Comment: @bitfizzy if the script is loaded dynamically via ajax, it won't show up in sources, but if you're so inclined, Firebug for Firefox does a better job of showing these sorts of "late binding" js resources (or it used to - have not used it in some time)

Comment: @bitfizzy - $('input:hidden').val() assignment would fail if not found in the DOM.  Your rendered HTML should make it clear if this selector is valid or not.

Comment: The issue with the script stopping after `$('input:hidden').val(secondsTracked);` turned out to be due to the fact that I was using a jQuery plugin (which I was using a function from) incorrectly :)

Comment: @JECarterII Thanks for the nod. I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

For any future readers interested in the solution, here's how I got around the issue (huge thanks to the helpful commenters above).

I added an event listener to the form in **track.js.erb**, which is triggered when the button is clicked (but before the form actually submits and sends data to the controller). Here it is:

```
var actual_form = $("#new_project", $(timeTrackingForm.document));

$(actual_form).submit(function(){ 
        $(timer).timer('pause');
        timerPaused = true;
        var secondsTracked = $(timer).data('seconds');
        $(hidden).val(secondsTracked);
        resetTimerDisplay();
    });
```